# Match nested characters into their meanings with Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

First of all I'm a toddler when it comes to regular expressions.

I need to match nested characters with their meanings stored in an array.

For example, given this string

> {(((x)))}

I need to translate it into this using either Regexp or oldschool for loops

> Inside curly braces, inside three parenthesis, one x mark, closed by three parenthesis, closed by curly braces

Problem is I need to parse many nested characters including unicode symbols, and I want to know if there is a best practice using regular expressions.

**Further examples:**

The input string will always be a palindrome.

```
{(#x#)} 
{{{{*}}}}
<<<x>>>
```

will be translated into their definitions from a static Array

```
String[][] openers = { {"{","curly"} , {"(","parenthesis" }, {"<","inequality"} };
String[][] insiders = { {"x","x mark"}, {"#","pound"}, {"*","star"} };
```

into these

> curly parenthesis pound x mark pound parenthesis curly
>
> four curly star four curly
>
> three inequality x mark three inequality

This will be done in Java by the way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a concreate example? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, one example isn't enough because you haven't shown how the input can vary and how your code should handle the differences.  Either post the actual requirements or enough examples that the requirements are self-evident.

Comment: I have added further examples. Input is a palindrome with few symbols inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go with regular expressions, but with a simple "map" instead, of String -> String, something like :

```
Map<String,String> explanations = new HashMap<String,String>();
explanations.put("{","inside curly braces");
```

You can then implement a simple iteration over the given string, that takes single characters and convert them.

To implement the "inside three parentesis" you could use Java internationalization system, so you can write "inside {0} parentesis" and then, in the parser, when you meet the same char more than once, increment a counter and use it to format the string properly. Given that the syntax is quite powerful, you can easily manage to handle singulars, plurals etc..

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with a temporary map and increment the counts while I iterate over the input string. I guess no easy way around with regular expressions is possible.

Comment: I do agree, regexs are powerful beasts, but still beasts :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't match **nested** parenthesis with a regular expression, it's not [powerful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) enough because it doesn't have a stack.

I recommend doing the parsing ad hoc with a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Or a simpler approach would be to remove the nesting iteratively like so:

```
for (...) {
   String s = s.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "$1")
   // do something
}
```

Comment: You cannot match arbitrarily deep nesting. You can certainly match and remove the outermost paired brackets, remove them, and loop; and you can certainly write a regular expression to pick apart well-formed paired brackets to a particular depth, but coping with errors is a drag, and the expression will be hard to write and debug for any nontrivial depths, and anyway, a real parser is a better tool for this.